# Jenkins at port 8080 stops when building in a job

Tags: jenkins, next.js, digital-ocean

I have a problem with Jenkins and could not find a solution yet.

I have a basic DO droplet with Jenkins connected to a gitHub. I have created a pipeline with webhook connected to a repository that contains a blog with Next.js, so when a new commit is pushed, the job starts. This job has 3 stages; first npm install, second npm build and finally pm2 reload.

I can connect to Jenkins via 8080 port and everything works fine, however, when a new job is triggered, just when the job starts building (second stage) the connection to Jenkins is broken and can nor connect to port 8080 anymore unless Jenkins is restarted in the terminal. However, the job continues being executed.

Trying to figure out what is happening but have no clue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try exposing your jenkins at different port other than 8080.(Can be done in jenkin.xml config file followed by restarting jenkins service)
There might be a priority service that starts up with 8080 port.

Comment: I tried what you propose; changed the port to 8081, not in config.xml but in /etc/default/jenkins and still happening the same. Is like if Jenkins runs out memory and stops.

Comment: Could be Possible reason. Try increasing heapsize. In the Java Options field, add the parameter -Xmx2000m

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! As I said; it was like Jenkins was running out memory, so I increased the droplet height to 2GB RAM and now everything is working fine.